# Freeradius doesn't work after updated Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, freeradius

Not good at unix like OS, your help is needed!
installed FreeRADIUS Version 3.0.16 on ubuntu 16.04 + radiusdesk+mysql ,after upgrading to 18.04 it no longer starts with an error that

```
"/etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf [653]: Failed reading directory /etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled/: No such file or directory"
```

I understand that he reads the config from this folder, but I cannot understand what is the reason, change either the path for reading the config, and if so, where, or you need to somehow transfer the config, I don't know where the problem and how repair

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is simple - the `/etc/freeradius/3.0/mods-enabled` directory doesn't exist, so can't be read. The question is why.

This may be related to the Debian/Ubuntu packages moving the FreeRADIUS configuration. It used to be in `/etc/freeradius`, but at some point was moved to `/etc/freeradius/3.0`. You could check to see if config files are still present in the original location and if so move them to the `3.0` subdirectory. If you do this then there may be config lines in `/etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf` (for example the `raddbdir` option) that need to be adjusted for the new location.

Otherwise you would do well to look at a backup from before the upgrade and copy the config from there to the new `/etc/freeradius/3.0` directory in the upgraded system. It sounds possible that something in the upgrade process broke the configuration in some way. Manually restoring a previous copy would be the simplest way to fix it.